# Is there such a thing as Edit Weight?

Tags: discussion, edits

If not, is there a large enough quantity of edits to warrant such a thing?

Not a feature request as such, just a product of curiosity.

Comment: There's at least a [list of editors](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors) now

Comment: I think you *should* make it a feature-request.

Comment: @Jim: I think having never seen the mod tools it would be quite presumptuous of me to propose improvements to them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For normal edits, there is no such thing tracked by the system itself because they don't get judged in any fashion mechanically.

For suggested edits, there *is* a countermeasure in which getting a lot of edit suggestions rejected will cause the user to be blocked from submitting more edit suggestions for a period of time. Your ratio of approved versus rejected edits is also tracked.

I don't think there's a weight system based on the ratio that affects the priority inside the edit queue.